# How to install language support in TexLive on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, package-management, latex

I'd like to use the [babel-croatian package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-croatian) which is available for download on CTAN. But how do I install this package? Or perhaps there is a command-line way?

Answer (score 3):

Just install the `texlive-lang-european` package.
The description includes babel-croatian.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package texlive-lang-european

Comment: My mistake. It is in testing/unstable. I'm not sure about stable. Maybe you'll have to install a more recent version of tex live.

Comment: I've found a better solution: writelatex.com. I'm starting to feel tired by this whole Linux mess

Comment: @overdriven - very sorry to hear that. Using Linux is like driving with a manual transmission, takes some getting used to but is much more enjoyable.

Comment: Try `texlive-lang-croatian` instead. This one is in stable.

Answer (score 2):

Debian's TeXlive packages often group many related CTAN packages. You can browse the list of `texlive-…` packages to find the one you want. If you know the specific file name that you're after, for example `croatian.ldf` for the Babel language definition file for Croatian, you can look it up [on the website](https://packages.debian.org/#search_contents) or use the [`apt-file`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-file) command:

```
apt-file search croatian.ldf
```

In wheezy, this file is in [`texlive-latex-base`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/texlive-latex-base) (which contains all the language definition files that Debian ships). There is an additional package [`texlive-lang-croatian`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/texlive-lang-croatian) with hyphenation support, documentation and other tools for typesetting Croatian.

The same principle would apply to fonts (assuming they're in Debian) — but Croatian doesn't use a specific font.